# Adjust page function, when changing device, just reloading works

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, responsive

I have a function to determine the height of the page, so that the page always stays at the maximum size regardless of the device, without scrolling.

I first take the maximum height of `let s = $ (document) .height` and then the height of all other elements, such as the header, main footer and footer. I subtract the value of all items by the variable `s`, which contains the height total. I assign the result to the main height value, so the page is the way I want it.

However, when I change the device to chrome inspection feature, or I leave it in landscape, the page is irregular. So be sure to reload, try using `windows.resize` by calling a function, but it doesn't adjust, just reloads. I don't know what to do.

I call the function like this:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
    changesize();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        changesize();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you couldn't use css to accomplish this? `height: 100vh` will keep an element at the viewport height even when resized, and using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) or [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) you could stretch and scale the main layout elements however you need them.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header, footer {
  background: aliceblue;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <header><h1>header</h1></header>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</section>
```